# Create UObject from another class with constructor

Tags: c++, oop, object, constructor, unreal-engine4

I have a class, describing some object with properties, e.g. inventory item.
And along with default constructor, I need parametrized constructor, to create items with certain set of parameters, for example, size)

```
UCLASS()
class xxx_API UItem : public UObject
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
public:
    UItem();
    ~UItem();
    UItem(int _size);

    UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadOnly, Category = "Parameters")
        int size = 0;
};
```

And I have another class, which I want to serve as container for pre defined items, so I can have references to it from other places of the game.

```
UCLASS()
class xxxx_API UItemsContainer : public UObject
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
public:
    UItemsContainer();
    ~UItemsContainer();

    UItem SomeItem = UItem(100);
};
```

So I can at the begiining of game create this item container

```
ItemsContainer = NewObject<UItemsContainer>();
```

And then add it to some item collection of certain entity like this

```
TArray<UItem*> CharacterItems = {};
CharacterItems.Add(&ItemsContainer.SomeItem);
```

Since items are fixed and will not change during game, I dont want to create specific object for each of them, and just have references to container entries.

Though on compilation I get error, that I try to access private members of UItem class. Though, it's constructor is public and all properties are public. I think that there is something in UClass, that dont allow me to use constructor that way, since I can do this with objects, that are not UObject. But I need it to be UObject, to be usable in blueprints. And I dont know how to call non-default constructor in other way.
Probably I can create default object with NewObject, and then initialize it and store in array, but looks like there will be too much code and complication.
Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because C++ has been stylized in Unreal, e.g. auto generated source file of `UItem` is in the directory:

```
MyProj\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Inc\MyProj\Item.generated.h
```

You can open this source, the copy-constructor of `UItem` has been shadowed, and `UItem SomeItem = UItem();` would trigger copy-constructor, so you will get a compilation error that try to access private members of UItem class.

[image]

In Unreal, you must invoke `NewObject` when creating UObject, e.g.

```
SomeItemPtr = NewObject<UItem>(Outer);
```

If you want to pass parameters on creating UObject, you can define a specific function

```
void UItem::SetParams(int Size)
{
    //initiation ...
}
```

e.g.

```
UItemsContainer::AddItem(int ItemSize)
{
    SomeItemPtr = NewObject<UItem>(this);
    SomeItemPtr->SetParams(ItemSize);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for info. Think it will be bad idea to mess with auto generated files, so will use NewObject then.